# How to show count_apply in field from count the data in PostgreSQL with Lumen

Tags: sql, postgresql, lumen

I want to ask again about PostgreSQL with framework Lumen. I have a table with implementation clone in the same table. For the difference I use parent_id for the clone row the true data reference on id. I count the data from another table but only counting the clone data not the true data.

Here is the image of result query:

[image: result query]

Clone data have the count_apply but I want that count_apply also show in the true data. I want the result like this image:

[image]

How to query that's data? Here's my code.

```
select
    "requisitions"."id",
    "requisitions"."title",
    "requisitions"."parent_id",
    (select count(id) from requisition_users where requisition_id = requisitions.id) AS count_apply,
    "requisitions"."status"
from
    "requisitions"
    inner join "users" on "requisitions"."created_by" = "users"."id"
    inner join "companies" on "requisitions"."company_id" = "companies"."id" 
    -- inner join "requisition_users" on "requisitions"."id" = "requisition_users"."requisition_id"
where
    "requisitions"."entity_id" = 1 
    -- and "requisitions"."parent_id" is not null
    -- and "requisitions"."status" >= 5
    -- and (select count(id) from requisition_users where requisition_id = requisitions.id) > 0
    -- and "requisitions"."parent_id" = "requisitions"."id"
    and "requisitions"."deleted_at" is null
```

Comment: show us your desired output as well

Comment: i already edited my post, i added the result i want, please help me to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know the data structure of your tables I have write an outer query to get you the result you want. Please try this and let me know if you face any difficulties:

```
select   
    "id",
    "title",
    "parent_id",
    (case when count_apply>0 then count_apply else max(count_apply)over(partition by "title") end)count_apply,
    "status" 
from
(select
    "requisitions"."id",
    "requisitions"."title",
    "requisitions"."parent_id",
    (select count(id) from requisition_users where requisition_id = requisitions.id) AS count_apply,
    "requisitions"."status"
from
    "requisitions"
    inner join "users" on "requisitions"."created_by" = "users"."id"
    inner join "companies" on "requisitions"."company_id" = "companies"."id" 
    -- inner join "requisition_users" on "requisitions"."id" = "requisition_users"."requisition_id"
where
    "requisitions"."entity_id" = 1 
    -- and "requisitions"."parent_id" is not null
    -- and "requisitions"."status" >= 5
    -- and (select count(id) from requisition_users where requisition_id = requisitions.id) > 0
    -- and "requisitions"."parent_id" = "requisitions"."id"
    and "requisitions"."deleted_at" is null)t
```

Comment: Please let me know if you face any difficulties.